# Won't this just break out of the if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, case, break

So basically given the below code.

When `action = 2;` and `mode = 1` Will `i` ever be set to 2?

I am working on a colleagues code, and it is written like this, but I thought that break would just skip the if and continue the rest of `case 2`. So basically the if statement is pointless.

```
switch(action){

   case 1: i = 1; break;

   case 2: if(mode == 1)
           {
              break;
           }

           i = 2;
           break;

   case 3: i = 3; break;
```

Ive rewritten this as:

```
 case 2: if(mode != 1)
            i = 2;
         break;
```

But it is not the only place, and some more complex. If im going to refactor it I need some info that I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JLS section 14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#6842):

> A break statement transfers control out of an enclosing statement.
>
> BreakStatement:
>
> ```
>    break Identifieropt ;
> ```
>
> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing *`switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement*  (emphasis added) of the immediately enclosing method or initializer block; this statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer with a viable source.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such a thing as an "if loop." Break can never refer to an "if" statement.

See [Wasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784493/52573) for a pointer to the language specification.

Also, assuming that 1 <= action <= 3, your code simplifies to:

```
if(! (action == 2 && mode == 1)) {
     i = action;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your refactoring is correct if that's what you want to know.

Comment: True, but you didn't answer the question 'Won't this just break out of the if statement?' +1 for correctness, -1 for off-topicness

Answer (score 1):

If `action == 2` and `mode == 1`, `i = 2` will not be executed (why you don't test it? It would be faster than asking here).

But your improvement is anyways cleaner, I would use it.

Comment: Theres a bug somewhere thats executing something unexpectedly. But yea, maybe I should have written a test app for it. ;)

Comment: Just make a main method paste the code and add action = 2; mode = 1;, there's your test.